# Check if a string has specific ending, erase this ending, then write those strings according to two other conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image][image]I've got a problem with preparing a readable report from my system.

I have to extract strings from "sil.catalog_no".

Firstly, I have to check if a string has ending like '-UW' and delete it.

After that, I have to extract that string (without -UW already), BUT without first part before first '-' or second '-' depending if before first '-' there is 'US'.

I know it's messed up, but I don't know how to describe it other way.

I have already tried SUBSTRING, LEFT, RIGHT and something with CHARINDEX, but my program/database/sql version(?) seems not to operate on those things and I can't find any other solution than these mentioned. Maybe it's because I don't use them correctly, I don't know.

The examples of strings contained in sil.catalog_no are:

```
HU-98010587
US-HU-88136FYT-719-UW
```

So, in first example, I just have to check if there is '-UW' at the end. There isn't one, so I move to second step, and just remove 'HU-' and extract the rest which is '98010587'.

With the second one, I want to check and remove '-US' from the end. Then I want to erase whole 'US-HU-', because there is 'US' first and I want to get '88136FYT-719'.

EDIT:

After re-thinking the problem, I think I would like to know the way to erase specific parts of strings. Looking at image I've provided, I would like to erase all 'HU-', 'EMC-', 'US-', and '-UW' that appear in result.

Comment: I think the function `regexp_replace` can solve your problem.So you just want to get the columns that contain numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think the function `regexp_replace` can solve your problem. As below:

```
postgres=# select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('US-HU-88136FYT-719-UW','^([A-Z]+-)+',''),'(-[A-Z]+)+$','') as result;
    result    
--------------
 88136FYT-719
(1 row)

postgres=# select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('HU-98010587','^([A-Z]+-)+',''),'(-[A-Z]+)+$','') as result;
  result  
----------
 98010587
(1 row)

postgres=# select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('EMC-C13-PWR-7','^([A-Z]+-)+',''),'(-[A-Z]+)+$','') as result;
  result   
-----------
 C13-PWR-7
```

Or we remove the `'HU-', 'EMC-', 'US-', '-UW'` more precisely, as below:

```
postgres=# select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('HU-98010587','^(HU-|EMC-|US-)+',''),'(-UW)+$','') as result;
  result  
----------
 98010587
(1 row)

postgres=# select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('US-HU-88136FYT-719-UW','^(HU-|EMC-|US-)+',''),'(-UW)+$','') as result;
    result    
--------------
 88136FYT-719
(1 row)

postgres=# select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('EMC-C13-PWR-7','^(HU-|EMC-|US-)+',''),'(-UW)+$','') as result;
  result   
-----------
 C13-PWR-7
(1 row)

postgres=# select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('US-HU-88134UGQ-UW','^(HU-|EMC-|US-)+',''),'(-UW)+$','') as result;
  result  
----------
 88134UGQ
```

I think the two regular expressions above may get the right result both, and the second would accurately match your needs. Just try it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194206/discussion-on-answer-by-shawn-x-check-if-a-string-has-specific-ending-erase-thi).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (tried on Postgres but also works even where there is no regex, like with SQLite3):

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(s varchar(30));
insert into t values
  ('HU-98010587'),
  ('US-HU-88136FYT-719-UW'),
  ('EMC-C13-PWR-7'),
  ('EMC-CTX-OM4-10M');

with xxx(original,s) as (
  select s,substr(s,1,length(s)-3) from t where s like '%-UW'
  union
  select s,s from t where s not like '%-UW'
  )
select original,substr(s,4) s from xxx where s like 'HU-%'
union
select original,substr(s,7) s from xxx where s like 'US-HU-%'
union
select original,s from xxx where s not like 'HU-%' and s not like 'US-HU-%';
```

To get what you say in your edit `I would like to erase all 'HU-', 'EMC-', 'US-', and '-UW' that appear in result`:

```
select s original,
  replace(
   replace(
    replace(
     replace(s,'HU-','')
     ,'US-','')
    ,'-UW','')
   ,'EMC-','') s
  from t;
```